# Jquery Datepicker as per asp.net dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to show jquery datepicker as per dropdownlist.For example if i choose june, it show only june month and rest of the month should freezed.!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify options to control such behaviour i.e. with `minDate` and `maxDate`, perhaps:

```
$(".date-selector").datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2013, 7, 1),
  maxDate: new Date(2013, 7, 31)
});
```

Comment: i want to display as per dropdownlist,if i selected jul it should show july month date (1 to 31) likewise feb ( 1 to 28)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in drop down for month thats turned on using the changeMonth parameter. That may be a better way for you.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: thnk for your reply.how to freeze other months